# is there a 'git find'?

Tags: git

Is there a `git find` analogue of `git grep`, i.e., something that will find a filename by pattern in the tree? I've gone through a lot of git documentation and not found this, but I'm having a hard time believing it doesn't exist somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list all files in a tree object using `git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree <treeish>`. Pipe this through a regular grep to find what you're looking for.

Comment: how about just `git ls-files` and pipe that through grep?

Comment: `git ls-files` only lists files that are currently present. Geoff's answer will show *all* files in the tree, including files that were deleted in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`git-ls-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html) and run the output through `grep(1)`

Answer (score 1):

It's simply:

```
git ls-files 'yourpattern'
```

Comment: that almost works; it uses globs rather than regexps, and requires me to say `ls-files **/filename` rather than `ls-files filename`. seems weird that git can do regexp searches through the contents of files but not through their filenames.